# Xdebug via VS Code remote?

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

My setup is a remote server running Docker. I connect to the remote via VS Code's remote SSH.

I make web requests threw a reverse proxy. That being said here is my Xdebug config options in the php.ini:

```ini
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = "host.docker.internal" ; Linux
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = ${XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT}
```

Right now I have the `XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT = 9998`. I have also confirmed from inside the docker container that `host.docker.internal` resolves to `72.24.0.1`.

I have tried to run `nc -vz localhost 9998` from the host machine and it works fine so I know VS Code is listening. If I try `nc -vz host.docker.internal 9998` from inside the docker container it fails to connect.

This is where it gets a bit weird. If I try that same `nc` command on my local machine from inside the docker container it works just fine.

If I run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` on the remote host I get:

[image]

So at this point I have no idea why the `nc` works on local but wont work when connected via SSH.

Also here is my launch.json in which I added the hostname so it would bind to the v4 IP address rather than the v6:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9998,
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/www"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": -1,
                "max_depth": 1,
                "max_children": 100

            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have this line in my docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" # Linux host
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I use a similar setup, but with Vagrant, not Docker... But I have a portforward from the guest to the host on the debug port... and this is my xdebug config: https://github.com/JoSSte/BasicLamp/blob/master/conf/xdebug.ini

Comment: Just gave the port forward a try with no luck.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I actually tried to convert my setup to docker... I abandoned it because of some issues with database initialization (I have some db seed scripts running on first build of the image) But i do not remember if I got debug working - I think i still have the branch in my repo, so I can have a look...

Comment: If you get a chance to check it out that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I checked out the branch, but I couldn't find any debug config. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look